# Portions of conic inside triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to figure out which segments of a given conic section curve lie inside a given triangle.
[image]

The specific triangle I’m dealing with is the one where $x\ge 0$, $y\ge 0$ and $x+y \le 1$, as shown in yellow in the picture.

I also have a conic section curve (the pale green thing), and I know its equation, in the form
$$
ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy +2fx + 2gy + c =0
$$
The example picture shows an ellipse, but the curve could be a parabola or hyperbola instead, of course.

I know how to calculate the intersection points with the sides of the triangle. There might be zero, two, four, or six of these. The example picture shows six intersections — the red points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$. Now consider all 15 possible pairs of points, like $(A,B)$, $(A,C)$, $(A,D)$ $,\dots,$ $(E,F)$. I want to know which of these pairs correspond to "good" segments of the conic, i.e. ones that lie inside the triangle, as shown in blue in the picture.

In my example, the pairs $(A,B)$, $(C,E)$, and $(D,F)$ are the good ones. $(A,C)$ is bad because it's outside the triangle, and $(A,E)$ is bad because it passes outside the conic at point $C$.

**How do I identify the "good" pairs?** I think there are at most three of them.

Motivation (if you need some): this is a part of a new “slicing” algorithm for 3D printing.

**Added**:
People keep assuming the intersection configuration shown in my original picture. My fault, possibly. Here are a few other possible ones as food for thought:

[image]

Comment: You might need the equations of the sides segments (lines). Points values of the conic will have a sign difference if inside or outside the triangle.

Comment: Yes, certainly. I explained what the equations of the sides are; they are $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x+y=1$.

Comment: I think that A, B has the higher y value. D, F the higher x values.

Comment: @Blue. Thanks. But the conic isn’t necessarily an ellipse, and there are many different intersection configurations. So, as you say, more thinking needed.

Comment: Let’s talk about the case of an ellipse intersecting with the given triangle. There exists maximum six common points as shown in the diagram. But, it is possible these two figures to have only four, two, or no common points. Do we have to consider those cases as well?

Comment: @YNK. Yes, the algorithm should work with any number of intersection points. I modified the question to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: ConicAndTriangle]

We have to assume a few things first. We assume that you know the coordinates of the three vertices of the right-angled triangle $UVW$. It is also necessary to know that pairs of points ($A$ and $B$), ($C$ and $D$), and ($E$ and $F$) lie on the sides $UV$, $VW$, and $WU$ respectively.

Now, you need to do some calculations. Start by computing the distances $UA$ and $UB$. Our aim here is to find which point, $A$ or $B$, is closer to the vertex $U$. If $UA \lt UB$, then $A$ is closer to $U$ than $B$ and vice versa.  Let’s say that $A$ is closer to $U$, then we know that $B$ is closer to the vertex $V$ than $A$. In a similar vein, find out which remaining four points of intersection are closer to which vertices $U$, $V$, and $W$ by computing the distances $VC$, $VD$, $WE$, and $WF$.

Assume that we have found out that the two points of intersection $A$ and $F$ are closer to $U$. Then, that means the arc $AF$ is inside the triangle. Continue in this manner to find the other two arcs, which lie inside the triangle.

To keep calculations simple and easy, you can place the vertex $V$ of the triangle at the origin of the coordinate system if possible.

Now, tell us whether this method is correct, feasible, accurate, and efficient enough.

Comment: Thanks. I don’t know if the method is correct because I’m having trouble imagining how it would apply to other intersection configurations. I added pictures of other ones to the question. I have no worries about the efficiency or accuracy of the method.

Comment: The triangle vertices are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. I don’t think your method works. Look at the first and second of the new pictures. They have the same intersection points, so the same distances, but different good segments. Am I missing something??

Comment: @bubba I composed this answer while I was waiting for a response from you to my earlier comment. The method described in my answer can be applied if and only if the configuration has the maximum possible number of intersections between the triangle and the conic. For other cases, where there are less than six points of intersection, we need additional guidance and directives to take care of the missing intersections. In an algorithm, these additions must proceed the method I described in my answer. I will see what I can do.